# Logging haproxy check results / problems

Tags: monitoring, logging, haproxy

how can I enable logging of haproxy check results (or failures only)? I've seen some mailing list posts suggesting [this is possible](http://www.mail-archive.com/haproxy@formilux.org/msg01851.html):

```
Server LDAPSFarm/LDAPS1 is DOWN, reason: Socket error, check duration: 277ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
```

but I don't get the same results. My config is more of less this:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1 local0
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        spread-checks 5

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        redispatch
        maxconn 2000

        stats enable
        stats hide-version

        option allbackups

listen XXX YYY
        mode tcp
        balance roundrobin
        option httpchk /

        server XXX-1 ZZZ1 check port 8080 inter 2s rise 15 slowstart 10s
        server XXX-2 ZZZ2 check port 8080 inter 2s rise 15 slowstart 10s
```

If I enable statistics page and look at it, I can see that sometimes server lines go yellow/red which suggests monitoring failures, but currently I don't see anything related in the log files. How can I get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out a reason. The version of haproxy I used simply didn't log the failure messages.

Answer (score 2):

i think  it's  nothing about  haproxy version, you may need add a line with

```
"option  log-health-checks"
```

in  configuration file of haproxy. like below

```
defaults
        log     global
        mode    tcp
        option  tcplog
        option  log-health-checks
        option  dontlognull
        option  dontlog-normal
        option  redispatch
```

Comment: I am using log-health-checks with Haproxy 1.5 ... it only logs the fact that the HTTP content did not match; it does not log the actual content.

Answer (score 1):

Is your syslog server actually listening on 127.0.0.1 and is configured to log all local0.* messages somewhere?

Comment: Yes - I get the general log lines about starting up, etc. but no information about services going down/up

Comment: What version of haproxy do you run?